# Compile boost for android using Clang included with VS2015 Mobile Development

Tags: android, c++, boost, clang, visual-studio-2015

I am trying to compile boost for android (x86 for the moment) using clang that is provided with the VS2015 Mobile Development Tools. So far I have not been able to compile boost with clang at all, even for native. Here is the project-config.jam that I am using for the x86 android build:

```
using clang : androidr10e :
    C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r10e/toolchains/llvm-3.6/prebuilt/windows/bin/clang++ :
    <compileflags>--sysroot=C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r10e/platforms/android-19/arch-x86
    <compileflags>-fno-strict-aliasing
    <compileflags>-fomit-frame-pointer
    <compileflags>-O2
    <compileflags>-D__ANDROID__
    <compileflags>-DNDEBUG
    <compileflags>-g
    <compileflags>-lstdc++
    <compileflags>-IC:/ProgramData/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include
    <compileflags>-IC:/ProgramData/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/x86_64
    <compileflags>-D__GLIBC__
    <compileflags>-DBOOST_NO_INTRINSIC_WCHAR_T
    ;
```

and executing b2 with:

```
b2 toolset=clang-androidr10e target-os=android cxxflags="-std=c++11"  linkflags="-stdlib=libc++" threading=multi threadapi=pthread link=shared runtime-link=shared --prefix=C:\projects\3rdparty\boost_1_59_0_x86android
```

This gives the following errors

```
In file included from libs\atomic\src\lockpool.cpp:16:
In file included from .\boost/config.hpp:57:
In file included from .\boost/config/platform/linux.hpp:15:
C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include\cstdlib:111:9: error: no member named 'strtold' in the global namespace
using ::strtold;
      ~~^
C:/ProgramData/Microsoft/AndroidNDK/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include\cstdlib:129:9: error: no member named '_Exit' in the global namespace
using ::_Exit;
      ~~^

etc...

In file included from libs\system\src\error_code.cpp:16:
In file included from .\boost/system/error_code.hpp:14:
In file included from .\boost/system/config.hpp:14:
In file included from .\boost/predef/platform.h:14:
.\boost/predef/platform/mingw.h:34:13: fatal error: '_mingw.h' file not found
#   include <_mingw.h>
            ^
3 errors generated.
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you find a solution to the problem?

Comment: nope, I  modified the code to use c11 instead of the boost functionality that was in use.

Comment: Boost thinks that you compile it with mingw, that's not the case. Tell him he's wrong.